# how to customize the downloads folder location

Tags: html, css

So I've made a download button in HTML
the thing is the download destination is always on the default destination

how can I a button that will open a window like this [image: From VSC]

every time it hit the select folder the folder location will be saved and the download will begin to that folder ??